# Add checkbox to ListView while keeping onListItemClick

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, sqlite

I currently have an SQLite3 database that a user saves their data to through an EditText. A ListView is then used to display the date the EditText data was saved. Upon clicking the date in the ListView, the data the user saved is then presented.

I would like to add functionality that would allow a checkbox to be added to each ListView item that would indicate that the user would like to delete that datapoint.

What would be the best way to have a checkbox that can allow for the inclusion of a "delete" button, but also maintain the function that when a ListView item is clicked, it shows previously saved data?

I have previously tried:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,
            arrayDateList);
setListAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

But each time the item is clicked, it shows the previous item and selects the checkbox. I would like only to select the checkbox, or the list item, but not both. Would this also mean a change in the XML file, too?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Better go for a xml layout.

Comment: take a custom layout. and set Click listener for parent layout which will be for listItem click functionality and add click listener for delete button for delete functionality.

Comment: @Vinodh I think that having a separate click listener is a great idea. However, I've never done this before. Do you know of anywhere I could get more information on implementing two separate click listeners for the parent layout and the delete button? Thank you!

Comment: @Nigram Patro what would the XML layout look like? I currently have just the ListView.